# RMAN - Fail To Restore Oracle DB with CDB and PDB

Tags: oracle

I'm having some issues restoring an Oracle 12C database from one server into another one.

After trying this procedure:
1>Connect to the ORIGIN Database server
2> Create an rman script file:

```
CROSSCHECK ARCHIVELOG ALL;
CROSSCHECK BACKUP;  
DELETE EXPIRED
ARCHIVELOG ALL;
DELETE NOPROMPT OBSOLETE RECOVERY WINDOW OF 3 DAYS;
DELETE NOPROMPT EXPIRED BACKUP;
BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG TAG DAILY_BKP DELETE INPUT MAXSETSIZE=5G KEEP UNTIL TIME 'sysdate+3';   
spool log to '<bkp_logfile>';
EXIT;
```

2. Run the command:
   export ORACLE_SID=;rman target / @
3. After the backup finished, copy the files to the DESTINATION database server. Also copy the backup control files.
4. Connect to the DESTINATION database server
5. Create pfile:

```
     *.audit_file_dest='<Path1>\adump'
        *.audit_trail='db'
        *.compatible='12.2.0.0.0'
        *.control_files='<Path2>\control01.ctl','<Path2>\control02.ctl'
        *.db_block_size=8192
        *.db_domain=''
        *.db_name='CAODB01U'
        *.db_recovery_file_dest='<Path2>'
        *.db_recovery_file_dest_size=10737418240
        *.diagnostic_dest='<PAth Diagnostic>'
        *.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=CDBXDB)'
        *.enable_pluggable_database=true
        *.memory_target=2729m
        *.open_cursors=300
        *.processes=500
        *.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
        *.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
```

6. rman> target /
7. rman>startup nomount pfile='< pfile >'
8. rman>restore controlfile from '< Path of datafile >';
9. rman>Alter database mount;
10. rman>catalog start with '';
11. rman>restore database;
12. rman>recover database;
13. rman>alter database open resetlogs;

After the last step the message i get the message:

```
> RMAN-00571:
> =========================================================== RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS
> =============== RMAN-00571: =========================================================== RMAN-03002: failure of sql statement command at 05/20/2021 12:21:30
> ORA-01152: file 1 was not restored from a sufficiently old backup
> ORA-01110: data file 1: '<Path DB >\SYSTEM01.DBF'
```

As ive seen in all the procedures to restore it, that should be the way to do it , but it doesnt seems to be working. Does anyone have an idea of what im doing wrong?

Also, when i try with
restore database;
recover database;

it tells that there are some datafiles missing, but there shouldnt be missing because its supposed to be a full backup.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit confusing. Normally this is solved by feeding a few extra archives to the recovery process and issue a cancel.
Do this using sqlplus.
Let it recover an archive and when it asks for the next archive issue 'cancel'. Most of the times the database will open.